# Hide Drafts "Unread" count Apple Mail App (Mac)? (Not badge)

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, gmail

I'm using Google Inbox to create template emails, which are stored as "drafts" in IMAP.

I want to eliminate that number (in grey, same as unread count in other folders) from Mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Gmail Settings: "labels tab" - deselect folders ('drafts' in my case) from showing in IMAP
2. "Synchronize" mail account in Mail app ("Mailbox" menu bar)